# Excel VBA Function Works In Some Places But Not Others

Tags: vba, excel

I inserted the following simple function into a Module in my spreadsheet:

```
Function CellName(cel As Range) As Variant
Dim nm As Name
    For Each nm In Names
        If nm.RefersTo = "=" & cel.Parent.Name & "!" & cel.Address Then
            CellName = nm.Name
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
CellName = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

I just want to fill a column with the named variables of the cells in the adjacent column.

Weird thing is, this function works in some CELLS, but in others it throws an #N/A error. In cells that do have names.

Can anyone help me understand? I'm not a VBA expert; I did do some research on this Q but found only answers that were much to more complicated questions than this.

Thanks.

Comment: if there is a "defined name" for exactly (and only) the cell you used, then you will get that name (if there is more than one, then just the first it encounters). and if no "name" goes directly to this cell, then, you will get "`#N/A`". What in detail does not work here?

Comment: This function seems to work for me, it returns the #N/A value of the referent `cel` doesn't have a `Name`.

Comment: Names can be scoped to the workbook or to a worksheet. You're not qualifying the `Names` collection that you're iterating, so it's implicitly referring to `ThisWorkbook.Names` (or `ActiveWorkbook.Names`, ...not sure.. could be `ActiveSheet.Names` too.. isn't implicit stuff nice?) - is that taken into account? i.e. are all the names at the same scope?

Comment: Dirk: For example, cell D3 of sheet "model-input" has a value of 2.25%, and is assigned the name `third_pty_sales_costs_pct`. in cell E3, I have {=cellname(D3)}, which yields #N/A

In the same workbook, on sheet "inputs", cell C3, the value is 588,000 and the name is `property_size`. In cell D3, the formula  is {=cellname(C3)}, which yields "property_size".

See? I'm confounded. But then again, like I said, I'm no expert in this stuff.

Comment: Mat's Mug: I named the cells from within the sheet (i.e., I did NOT use VBA code to assign names to ranges, I did it manually.)

There are no sheet-level names (other than print areas & auto-filters)

Beyond that, I don't know the answer to your question, but am happy to take some light coaching on how to.

Comment: I will take a guess and say it doesn't work on sheets where the sheet name contains a space or other "strange" character.  In those cases the `RefersTo` looks like `"='" & cel.Parent.Name & "'!" & cel.Address Then`.  For instance, a `RefersTo` of `=model-input!$D$3` would be invalid because of the `-`, so the quotation marks are necessary to make it valid.

Comment: YowE3K: Yes! I NEVER would have caught that. (I found that function online, and copy-pasted it into a module in my workbook).

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to get the name wherever they are, you can use something like this:

```
Public Function CellName(cel As Range) As Variant
  Dim nm As Name, sht As Worksheet

  For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If nm.RefersTo = "=" & cel.Parent.Name & "!" & cel.Address Then
      CellName = nm.Name
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

  For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each nm In sht.Names
      If nm.RefersTo = "=" & cel.Parent.Name & "!" & cel.Address Then
        CellName = nm.Name
        Exit Function
      End If
    Next
  Next

  '----- skip from here if you only want single-cells

  For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If Not Intersect(Range(nm.RefersTo), cel) Is Nothing Then
      CellName = "* " & nm.Name
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

  For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each nm In sht.Names
      If Not Intersect(Range(nm.RefersTo), cel) Is Nothing Then
        CellName = "* " & nm.Name
        Exit Function
      End If
    Next
  Next

  '----- skip till here if you only want single-cells

CellName = CVErr(xlErrNA)

End Function
```

The second part will also show ranges which include the cell if no single-reference was found (output starts with `"* "` (can be deleted if there is no need)

Comment: Danke Dirk! I think this solves the problem YowE3K caught. Thank you both for the help. (Every one of these, I learn a little.)

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your function to this:

```
Function CellName(cel As Range) As Variant
    Dim nm As Name
    For Each nm In Names
        If nm.RefersTo = "=" & cel.Parent.Name & "!" & cel.Address Or _
           nm.RefersTo = "='" & Replace(cel.Parent.Name, "'", "''") & "'!" & cel.Address Then
            CellName = nm.Name
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    CellName = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

Some sheet names need to be enclosed in quotation marks in order for syntax rules to be preserved.

Edit:  Based on a comment from David Zemens, I have updated the formula to perform a `Replace(cel.Parent.Name, "'", "''")` to ensure that any embedded quotation marks in the sheet name are replaced by two quotation marks.

Comment: @DavidZemens - no, that won't work - take for example a sheet called `Sh e'et1`.  A `RefersTo` to cell A1 will be `='Sh e''t1'!$A$1`.  `Replace(nm.RefersTo, "'",vbNullString)` will therefore give `=Sh et1!$A$1` which won't match `=Sh e't1!$A$1`.  You would have to do the replace on both sides of the equation, which would then give issues if you had sheets called `Sh e'et1` **and** `Sh eet1`.  (Why anyone would have sheets with those names is another question entirely!!)

Comment: Ahhh you're right I assumed `'` was illegal character in sheetname :)

Comment: @DavidZemens - I have used the Replace on the `cel.Parent.Name` - that should fix things.  (I expected that `'` would be invalid in sheet names too - it's surprising what is and isn't permitted.)

Comment: The one Dirk wrote (the answer I checked above) worked. :)